# how to modify database in android

Tags: android

hi i am new to Android.what i did is i am creating a sqllitedatabase in class A.I am creating a table and inserting the some values.Now what i need is i have to insert some more values from class B to the same database.how can i done this.pls help me.Thank u in advance.

Comment: Are you trying this on Iphone or Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1763?supportItem=4